# use IN statement within ID column and retrieve count(*)?

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL command:

```
SELECT * from products 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT product_id, count(*)
  FROM account_products
  GROUP BY product_id
)
```

obviously it doesnt retrieve any data, because the internal query retrieves two columns (product_id and count).
But I need the count too, because I'm gonna use it to make some math later.
How can I use this IN query using the count(*) too?

Thanks!

Comment: which RDBMS (product and version)?

Comment: You need to explain more about how you are going to use the count later.  The bast option may be a temporary table, or a common table expression if you want to reuse the subquery later on in the same query.  `IN` clauses require that only one column is returned (some systems may just ignore columns after the first one)

Answer (score 4):

Join them:

```
select products.*, t.product_count
from products
  join (
    SELECT product_id, count(*) as product_count
    FROM account_products
    GROUP BY product_id
  ) as t on t.product_id = products.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select products.*, count( account_products.product_id)
from products join account_products on
  products.product_id = products.id
group by products.* (obviously all products-fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with a subquery in the select clause, when your DBMS supports it:

```
SELECT 
  products.*, 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM account_products ap WHERE ap.product_id = products.id) as "Number of Accounts"
from products
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
WITH MyAccountProducts AS
(
  SELECT product_id, count(*) AS CountOfAccountProducts
  FROM account_products
  GROUP BY product_id
)
SELECT p.*,ap.CountOfAccountProducts
from products AS p
INNER JOIN MyAccountProducts AS ap ON p.id=ap.product_id
```